# Magento 2 A technical problem while saving some product from backend

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am getting below error while saving some configurable product not all products.

`A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.`

https://prnt.sc/pc0pu4

Comment: please check your logs for exact error

Comment: I have checked but there is only one error is showing    2019-09-26 10:17:32] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor" [] []

Comment: Can you try disabling index on save if you haven't already

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug in the `Magento 2.3` version, but you can fix the issue by the change in the below code.

You can go to this file: `/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml` and please remove "**fileUploader**" and add "**imageUploader**".

```
<collapsible>true</collapsible>
                <label translate="true">HTML Head</label>
            </settings>
            <!-- Remove this code -->
            <!-- <field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="fileUploader">-->

            <!-- Add this code -->
            <field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="imageUploader">
                <settings>
                    <notice translate="true">Not all browsers support all these formats!</notice>
                    <label translate="true">Favicon Icon</label>

                <collapsible>true</collapsible>
                <label translate="true">Header</label>
            </settings>
            <!-- Remove this code -->
            <!-- <field name="header_logo_src" formElement="fileUploader"> -->

            <!-- Add this code -->
            <field name="header_logo_src" formElement="imageUploader">
                <settings>
                    <label translate="true">Logo Image</label>
                    <componentType>imageUploader</componentType>
```

Please check this will help you.

Comment: I know this solution work but it only works for logo image uploading.

Comment: Ok @Vikaskalal can you please try with this link. https://tutes.in/solved-magento-2-error-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-try-again-to-continue-what-you-were-doing-if-the-problem-persists-try-again-later/

Comment: i am not showing this error anywhere and this is not actual solution for this error i am getting this error only saving product.and some product not all product

Comment: It is usual problem sir. And it will come some times and sometime not.
But just some other people solved it with this solutions so I also told you and one time when I have I also solved with this so just give you for product if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

If it happen only when you try to save configurable product, than just go to your server settings php.ini and make sure your **max_input_vars** is set up right. It can be more or less it depend on how many variations is added to your attribute that is used for configurable product. This issue can happen when you try to save attribute with many variations as well. 
You can try max_input_vars = 10000